# Unable to permanently turn off time stamp display in QGIS Time Manager

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, time

Using QGIS 2.10.1 Time Manager, I wish to permanently turn off the time stamp display for one particular project.  In Time Manager Plugin > Settings I uncheck "Display frame start time on map".  The time display correctly disappears.  However, when I save the project file and then reopen it later, "Display frame start time on map" is now checked on, and the time stamp displays.

How do I permanently turn off the time display for this project file?

Comment: Not sure that feature is implemented at the moment. It seems that the _Time display options_ are not saved and gets reset when the plugin loads up with QGIS. I'm sure [@underdark](http://gis.stackexchange.com/users/187/underdark) will be able to respond to this as she is one of the two developers. Also, I think this [issue](https://github.com/anitagraser/TimeManager/issues/109) has been identified.